# ssis - Visual Studio does not seem to be finding the “Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable”

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I know there are a number of questions relating to SSIS and the  “*Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable”*, but none of them seems to solve my problem.

I have **Visual Studio 2005** running onn a **64bit machine**. I have successfully downloaded and installed the 64bit Database Engine, as I can see it in Control Panel program list. However, there is no sign of *"Micosoft Access"* etc when I attempt to create a new OLE DB connection within SSIS. I need this to read Excel xlsx files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do, connect to a Access Database? I know for instance you need to install this driver if you want to use excel as a source as well (for a certain version of office and up if not mistaken.)

Comment: @InusC. Thanks. I need the driver to read .xlsx files. I've amended my question accordingly. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No problem, I have not worked with 2005 unfortunately, so hope I am not wasting your time. Not sure if this might help, otherwise I am out.
http://bensullins.com/using-excel-2007-files-as-a-source-in-ssis-2005/

Comment: Don't you see `Excel Source` in the `Other Sources` section of the SSIS toolbox?

Comment: @InusC Thanks for the suggestion. This is basically what I am already trying. This solution depends on `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` being available to the project. However, my BIDS does not show this option, hence it does not work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Yes I do see `Excel source` in the `Other sources` but this does not work for Excel 2007 (xslm) files.